# Store output text from R SHINY to an object outside of the app

Tags: r, output, shiny

How can I store outputtext:

```
 output$text1 <- renderText({paste(input$atribute1,input$operator1)})
```

from R SHINY to an object outside of the app like:

```
objectusedoutside <- output$text1
```

Comment: try the global assignment operator `<<-` instead of `<-`. Like so inside the `server.R`: `output$text1 <- renderText({objectusedoutside <<- paste(input$atribute1,input$operator1) objectusedoutside)}`

Comment: Seems to work! Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can maybe use the global assignement operator `<<-` like so:

```
output$text1 <- renderText({
objectusedoutside <<- paste(input$atribute1,input$operator1) 
objectusedoutside)}
```

Now you can use the `objectusedoutside` object outside the app